# optimise knight-tour LISP

Tags: recursion, lisp, common-lisp, knights-tour

I am new to LISP and I encounter this problem with the below code.

```
(defun knights-tour-brute (x y m n) 
  (setq height m)     
  (setq width n)      
  (setq totalmoves (* height width))  
  (setq steps 1)      
  (setq visited-list (list (list x y))) 
  (tour-brute (list (list x y))))
(defun tour-brute (L)
  (cond
   ((null L) NIL)   
   ((= steps totalmoves) L)   
   (t
    (let ((nextmove (generate L)))
      (cond ((null nextmove) (backtrack (car (last L)))
                             (tour-brute (reverse (cdr (reverse L)))))
            (t (setq visited-list (append visited-list (list nextmove)))
               (tour-brute (append L (list nextmove))))))))) 

(defun generate (L)
  (let ((x (caar (last L))) 
        (y (cadar (last L)))) 
    (setq steps (+ 1 steps))  
    (cond
     ((correct-state(+ x 2) (+ y 1) L) (list (+ x 2) (+ y 1)))
     ((correct-state (+ x 2) (- y 1) L) (list (+ x 2) (- y 1)))
     ((correct-state (- x 1) (+ y 2) L) (list (- x 1) (+ y 2)))
     ((correct-state (+ x 1) (+ y 2) L) (list (+ x 1) (+ y 2)))
     ((correct-state (+ x 1) (- y 2) L) (list (+ x 1) (- y 2)))
     ((correct-state (- x 1) (- y 2) L) (list (- x 1) (- y 2)))
     ((correct-state (- x 2) (+ y 1) L) (list (- x 2) (+ y 1)))
     ((correct-state (- x 2) (- y 1) L) (list (- x 2) (- y 1)))
     (t (setq steps (- steps 2)) NIL))))

(defun correct-state (x y L)
  (if (and (<= 1 x)
           (<= x height)
           (<= 1 y)
           (<= y width)
           (not (visited (list x y) L))
           (not (visited (list x y) 
                (tail (car (last L)) visited-list)))) (list (list x y)) NIL))

(defun tail (L stateslist)
  (cond
   ((equal L (car stateslist)) (cdr stateslist))
   (t (tail L (cdr stateslist)))))

(defun visited (L stateslist)
  (cond
   ((null stateslist) NIL)   
   ((equal L (car stateslist)) t) 
   (t (visited L (cdr stateslist)))))

(defun backtrack (sublist)
  (cond
   ((null visited-list) t)
   ((equal sublist (car (last visited-list))) t)
   (t (setq visited-list (reverse (cdr (reverse visited-list)))) 
      (backtrack sublist))))
```

It returns me an error *** - Program stack overflow. RESET. When I was googling around, I realise that this is the result of recursion. However I am not sure how should I optimise this code to resolve this issue. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Hi, above is the updated code. This is the test code.
(knights-tour-brute 5 5 1 1)

Comment: It would be easier to help with runnable code, and a description of your algorithm. Which implementation are you using?

Comment: Hi I have updated the runnable code. Could you help me take a look? Thank you

Comment: First error: neither `steps` nor `total moves` are defined in `tour-brute`. If they are supposed to be global, they are not (they need to be defined with `defvar` or `defparameter` and have ear-muffs to distinguish from local variables).

Comment: My suspicion is that stack overflow is not because of the inefficiency of the algorithm (although could be), but because of infinite recursion somewhere in implementation.

Comment: Then is there a way I could overcome this problem?

Comment: Sorry I am still quite a newbie to this language. Three weeks old. So really need a lot of help.

Comment: Does it cause a stack overflow for you when you run it with `(knights-tour-brute 1 1 5 5)`? For me (on SBCL) it produces correct results, at least up to 6x6, but when the board is 8x8 it takes too long to compute and I haven't run it all the way yet. I haven't gotten stack overflow, so I imagine you must be using an implementation with no tail call optimisation (or you need to enable it with something like `(declaim (optimize (speed 3)))`). If you're not using SBCL, try with that and use that optimize directive before compiling the code.

Comment: Hi I am using clisp on mac OSX terminal. Is there a way to overcome that issue?

Comment: @Hero1134 Try using `(declaim (optimize (speed 3)))`, followed by `(compile-file "your file.lisp")` and then load the compiled file. If it still causes a stack overflow even with smaller (like 5x5) boards, try installing [sbcl](http://www.sbcl.org/) and do the same thing with it. The code does seem to have parts that could be optimised, but first you should make sure the TCO works. I'm not sure if a brute force algorithm is sufficient for a 8x8 board though, so you might need to think of some more efficient one later.

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in the comments, the problem is lacking [Tail Call Optimisation (TCO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). You might be able to enable that with

```
(declaim (optimize (speed 3)))
```

But it depends on your implementation. I'm not sure about CLISP.

**Edit: The other answers have more efficient ways for solving the problem, but it's still worth reading this answer for ways to write the original solution better**

Anyway, I optimised the code a bit. You will still need to have TCO in order to run it. That's an inherent problem of using recursion like this. It should run well under [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/) at least. Just save it into a file, and do

```
(load (compile-file "file.lisp"))
```

It should run must faster than your original code, and do much less memory allocation. The relevant numbers for `(time (knights-tour-brute 1 1 6 6))` with your code:

```
4,848,466,907 processor cycles
572,170,672 bytes consed
```

And my code:

```
1,155,406,109 processor cycles
17,137,776 bytes consed
```

For most part I left your code as is. The changes I made are mostly:

1. I actually declared the global variables and cleaned up some bits of the code.
2. In your version you build `visited-list` in order. That might seem intuitive when you don't understand how the singly linked lists in Lisp work, but it's very inefficient (those `(reverse (cdr (reverse list)))` were really eating performance). You should read some Lisp book regarding Lists. I keep it in reverse order, and then finally reverse it with `nreverse` at the end.
3. You used lists for the coordinates. I use a struct instead. Performance is very greatly increased.
4. I added type declarations for everything. It improves performance a little.

However, it is still the same brute force algorithm, so it will be very slow for larger boards. You should look into smarter algorithms for those.

```
(declaim (optimize (speed 3) (space 0) (safety 0) (debug 0)))

(declaim (type fixnum *height* *width* *total-moves* *steps*))
(declaim (type list *visited-list*))

(declaim (ftype (function (fixnum fixnum fixnum fixnum) list)
                knights-tour-brute))
(declaim (ftype (function (list) list)
                tour-brute))
(declaim (ftype (function (list) (or pos null))
                generate))
(declaim (ftype (function (fixnum fixnum list) (or t null))
                correct-state))
(declaim (ftype (function (fixnum fixnum list) (or t null))
                visited))
(declaim (ftype (function (pos) t)
                backtrack))
(declaim (ftype (function (fixnum fixnum pos) (or t null))
                vis-2))
(declaim (ftype (function (pos pos) (or t null))
                pos=))
(declaim (ftype (function (pos fixnum fixnum) (or t null))
                pos=*))

(defstruct pos
  (x 0 :type fixnum)
  (y 0 :type fixnum))

(defmethod print-object ((pos pos) stream)
  (format stream "(~d ~d)" (pos-x pos) (pos-y pos)))

(defparameter *height* 0)
(defparameter *width* 0)
(defparameter *total-moves* 0)
(defparameter *steps* 0)
(defparameter *visited-list* '())

(defun knights-tour-brute (x y m n)
  (let ((*height* m)
        (*width* n)
        (*total-moves* (* m n))
        (*steps* 1) 
        (*visited-list* (list (make-pos :x x :y y))))
    (nreverse (tour-brute (list (make-pos :x x :y y))))))

(defun tour-brute (l)
  (cond
    ((null l) nil)
    ((= *steps* *total-moves*) l)   
    (t (let ((nextmove (generate l)))
         (cond
           ((null nextmove)
            (backtrack (first l))
            (tour-brute (rest l)))
           (t (push nextmove *visited-list*)
              (tour-brute (cons nextmove l)))))))) 

(defun generate (l)
  (let ((x (pos-x (first l)))
        (y (pos-y (first l))))
    (declare (type fixnum x y))
    (incf *steps*)
    (cond
      ((correct-state (+ x 2) (+ y 1) l) (make-pos :x (+ x 2) :y (+ y 1)))
      ((correct-state (+ x 2) (- y 1) l) (make-pos :x (+ x 2) :y (- y 1)))
      ((correct-state (- x 1) (+ y 2) l) (make-pos :x (- x 1) :y (+ y 2)))
      ((correct-state (+ x 1) (+ y 2) l) (make-pos :x (+ x 1) :y (+ y 2)))
      ((correct-state (+ x 1) (- y 2) l) (make-pos :x (+ x 1) :y (- y 2)))
      ((correct-state (- x 1) (- y 2) l) (make-pos :x (- x 1) :y (- y 2)))
      ((correct-state (- x 2) (+ y 1) l) (make-pos :x (- x 2) :y (+ y 1)))
      ((correct-state (- x 2) (- y 1) l) (make-pos :x (- x 2) :y (- y 1)))
      (t (decf *steps* 2)
         nil))))

(defun correct-state (x y l)
  (and (<= 1 x *height*)
       (<= 1 y *width*)
       (not (visited x y l))
       (vis-2 x y (first l))))

(defun visited (x y stateslist)
  (loop
     for state in stateslist
     when (pos=* state x y) do (return t)))

;;---TODO: rename this
(defun vis-2 (x y l-first)
  (loop
     for state in *visited-list*
     when (pos= l-first state) do (return t)
     when (pos=* state x y) do (return nil)))

(defun backtrack (sublist)
  (loop
     for state in *visited-list*
     while (not (pos= sublist state))
     do (pop *visited-list*)))

(defun pos= (pos1 pos2)
  (and (= (pos-x pos1)
          (pos-x pos2))
       (= (pos-y pos1)
          (pos-y pos2))))
(defun pos=* (pos1 x y)
  (and (= (pos-x pos1) x)
       (= (pos-y pos1) y)))
```

**Edit: I improved `correct-state` so as to not look through the same list twice. Reduces consing significantly.**

**Edit2: I switched to using a struct for positions instead of using cons-cells. That improves performance dramatically.**

It could probably be optimised more, but it should be sufficiently fast for boards up 6x6. If you need better performance, I think switching to a different algorithm would be more productive than trying to optimize a brute force solution. If someone does want to optimize this anyway, here are some results from profiling.

Results from `sb-sprof` show that majority of time is spent in checking equality. I don't think there's much to be done about that. `visited` also takes quite a bit of time. Maybe storing the visited positions in an array would speed it up, but I haven't tried it.

```
           Self        Total        Cumul
  Nr  Count     %  Count     %  Count     %    Calls  Function
------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1   1631  40.8   3021  75.5   1631  40.8        -  VISITED
   2   1453  36.3   1453  36.3   3084  77.1        -  POS=*
   3    337   8.4   3370  84.3   3421  85.5        -  CORRECT-STATE
   4    203   5.1   3778  94.5   3624  90.6        -  GENERATE
   5    101   2.5    191   4.8   3725  93.1        -  VIS-2
   6     95   2.4     95   2.4   3820  95.5        -  POS=
   7     88   2.2   3990  99.8   3908  97.7        -  TOUR-BRUTE
   8     44   1.1     74   1.9   3952  98.8        -  BACKTRACK
   9     41   1.0     41   1.0   3993  99.8        -  MAKE-POS
```

:ALLOC mode doesn't give much usefull information:

```
           Self        Total        Cumul
  Nr  Count     %  Count     %  Count     %    Calls  Function
------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1   1998  50.0   3998  99.9   1998  50.0        -  TOUR-BRUTE
   2   1996  49.9   1996  49.9   3994  99.9        -  MAKE-POS
```

`sb-profile` shows that `generate` does most of the consing, while `visited` takes most of the time (note that the seconds of course are way off due to the instumentation):

```
  seconds  |     gc     |   consed   |    calls   |  sec/call  |  name  
-------------------------------------------------------------
     8.219 |      0.000 |    524,048 |  1,914,861 |   0.000004 | VISITED
     0.414 |      0.000 |     32,752 |    663,273 |   0.000001 | VIS-2
     0.213 |      0.000 |     32,768 |    266,832 |   0.000001 | BACKTRACK
     0.072 |      0.000 |          0 |  1,505,532 |   0.000000 | POS=
     0.000 |      0.000 |          0 |          1 |   0.000000 | TOUR-BRUTE
     0.000 |      0.024 | 17,134,048 |    533,699 |   0.000000 | GENERATE
     0.000 |      0.000 |     32,768 |  3,241,569 |   0.000000 | CORRECT-STATE
     0.000 |      0.000 |     32,752 | 30,952,107 |   0.000000 | POS=*
     0.000 |      0.000 |          0 |          1 |   0.000000 | KNIGHTS-TOUR-BRUTE
-------------------------------------------------------------
     8.918 |      0.024 | 17,789,136 | 39,077,875 |            | Total
```

Comment: Hey thanks jkiski. You are brilliant. The algo you gave is a brute force algo.

Answer (score 2):

The [list-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35443100/124319)
from @jkiiski takes the same approach as OP and greatly optimizes
it. Here the goal is different: I try to use another
way to represent the problem (but still brute force) and we can see that with vectors and
matrices, we can solve *harder* problems *better*, *faster* and *stronger*<sup>**1**</sup>.

I also applied the same heuristics as in the other answer, which significantly reduces the effort required to find solutions.

#### Data-structures

```
(defpackage :knight (:use :cl))
(in-package :knight)

(declaim (optimize (speed 3) (debug 0) (safety 0)))

(deftype board () '(simple-array bit *))
(deftype delta () '(integer -2 2))

;; when we add -2, -1, 1 or 2 to a board index, we assume the
;; result can still fit into a fixnum, which is not always true in
;; general.

(deftype frontier () (list 'integer -2 most-positive-fixnum))
```

Next, we define a class to hold instances of a Knight's Tour problem
as well as working data, namely height, width, a matrix representing
the board, containing either 0 (empty) or 1 (visited), as well as the
current tour, represented by a vector of size *height x width* with a
fill-pointer initialized to zero. The dimensions are not strictly necessary in this class since the internal board already stores them.

```
(defclass knights-tour ()
  ((visited-cells :accessor visited-cells)
   (board :accessor board)
   (height :accessor height :initarg :height :initform 8)
   (width :accessor width :initarg :width :initform 8)))

(defmethod initialize-instance :after ((knight knights-tour)
                                       &key &allow-other-keys)
  (with-slots (height width board visited-cells) knight
    (setf board (make-array (list height width)
                            :element-type 'bit
                            :initial-element 0)

          visited-cells (make-array (* height width)
                                    :element-type `(integer ,(* height width))
                                    :fill-pointer 0))))
```

By the way, we also specialize `print-object`:

```
(defmethod print-object ((knight knights-tour) stream)
  (with-slots (width height visited-cells) knight
    (format stream "#<knight's tour: ~dx~d, tour: ~d>" width height visited-cells)))
```

#### Auxiliary functions

```
(declaim (inline visit unvisit))
```

Visiting a cell at position *x* and *y* means setting a *one* at the
appropriate location in the board and pushing current cell's
coordinate into the *visited-cell* vector. I store the row-major index
instead of a couple of coordinates because it allocates less memory (in fact the difference is not important).

```
(defmethod visit ((knight knights-tour) x y)
  (let ((board (board knight)))
    (declare (board board))
    (setf (aref board y x) 1)
    (vector-push-extend (array-row-major-index board y x)
                        (visited-cells knight))))
```

Unvisiting a cell means setting a *zero* in the board and decreasing the
fill-pointer of the sequence of visited cells.

```
(defun unvisit (knight x y)
  (let ((board (board knight)))
    (declare (board board))
    (setf (aref board y x) 0)
    (decf (fill-pointer (visited-cells knight)))))
```

#### Exhaustive search

The recursive visiting function is the following one. It first visits
current cell, recursively calls itself on each free valid neighbour
and finally unvisits itself before exiting. The function accepts a
callback function to be called whenever a solution is found (edit: I won't refactor, but I think the callback function should be stored in a slot of the *knights-tour* class).

```
(declaim (ftype
          (function (knights-tour fixnum fixnum function)
                    (values &optional))
          brute-visit))

(defun brute-visit (knight x y callback
                    &aux (board (board knight))
                      (cells (visited-cells knight)))
  (declare (function callback)
           (board board)
           (type (vector * *) cells)
           (fixnum x y))
  (visit knight x y)
  (if (= (fill-pointer cells) (array-total-size cells))
        (funcall callback knight)
        (loop for (i j) of-type delta
                in '((-1 -2) (1 -2) (-2 -1) (2 -1)
                     (-2 1) (2 1) (-1 2) (1 2))
              for xx = (the frontier (+ i x))
              for yy = (the frontier (+ j y))
              when (and (array-in-bounds-p board yy xx)
                        (zerop (aref board yy xx)))
                do (brute-visit knight xx yy callback)))
  (unvisit knight x y)
  (values))
```

#### Entry point

```
(defun knights-tour (x y callback &optional (h 8) (w 8))
  (let ((board (make-instance 'knights-tour :height h :width w)))
    (brute-visit board x y callback)))
```

#### Tests 1

The following test asks to find a solution for a 6x6 board:

```
(time (block nil
        (knights-tour 0 0 (lambda (k) (return k)) 6 6)))

Evaluation took:
  0.097 seconds of real time
  0.096006 seconds of total run time (0.096006 user, 0.000000 system)
  [ Run times consist of 0.008 seconds GC time, and 0.089 seconds non-GC time. ]
  98.97% CPU
  249,813,780 processor cycles
  47,005,168 bytes consed
```

Comparatively, the version from the other versions runs as follows
(the origin point is the same, but we index cells differently):

```
(time (knights-tour-brute 1 1 6 6))

Evaluation took:
  0.269 seconds of real time
  0.268017 seconds of total run time (0.268017 user, 0.000000 system)
  99.63% CPU
  697,461,700 processor cycles
  17,072,128 bytes consed
```

#### Tests 2

For larger boards, the difference is more visible. If we ask to find a solution for an 8x8 board, the above versions acts as follows on my machine:

```
> (time (block nil (knights-tour 0 0 (lambda (k) (return k)) 8 8)))

Evaluation took:
  8.416 seconds of real time
  8.412526 seconds of total run time (8.412526 user, 0.000000 system)
  [ Run times consist of 0.524 seconds GC time, and 7.889 seconds non-GC time. ]
  99.96% CPU
  21,808,379,860 processor cycles
  4,541,354,592 bytes consed

#<knight's tour: 8x8, tour: #(0 10 4 14 20 3 9 19 2 8 18 1 11 5 15 21 6 12 22 7
                              13 23 29 35 25 40 34 17 27 33 16 26 32 49 43 28
                              38 55 61 44 59 53 63 46 31 37 47 30 36 51 57 42
                              48 58 52 62 45 39 54 60 50 56 41 24)>
```

The original list-based approach did not return and after ten minutes I killed
the worker thread.

#### Heuristics

There are still room for improvements (see actual research papers to have more information) and here I'll sort the neighbors like @jkiiski's updated version to see what happens. What follows is just a way to abstract iterating over neighbours, because we will use it more than once, and differently:

```
(defmacro do-neighbourhood ((xx yy) (board x y) &body body)
  (alexandria:with-unique-names (i j tx ty)
    `(loop for (,i ,j) of-type delta
             in '((-1 -2) (1 -2) (-2 -1) (2 -1)
                  (-2 1) (2 1) (-1 2) (1 2))
           for ,tx = (the frontier (+ ,i ,x))
           for ,ty = (the frontier (+ ,j ,y))
           when (and (array-in-bounds-p ,board ,ty ,tx)
                     (zerop (aref ,board ,ty ,tx)))
             do (let ((,xx ,tx)
                      (,yy ,ty))
                  ,@body))))
```

We need a way to count the number of possible neighbors:

```
(declaim (inline count-neighbours)
         (ftype (function (board fixnum fixnum ) fixnum)
                count-neighbours))

(defun count-neighbours (board x y &aux (count 0)) 
  (declare (fixnum count x y)
           (board board))
  (do-neighbourhood (xx yy) (board x y)
    (declare (ignore xx yy))
    (incf count))
  count)
```

And here is the alternative search implementation:

```
(defstruct next
  (count 0 :type fixnum)
  (x 0 :type fixnum)
  (y 0 :type fixnum))

(defun brute-visit (knight x y callback
                    &aux (board (board knight))
                      (cells (visited-cells knight)))
  (declare (function callback)
           (board board)
           (type (vector * *) cells)
           (fixnum x y))
  (visit knight x y)
  (if (= (fill-pointer cells) (array-total-size cells))
      (funcall callback knight)
      (let ((moves (make-array 8 :element-type 'next
                                 :fill-pointer 0)))
        (do-neighbourhood (xx yy) (board x y)
          (vector-push-extend (make-next :count (count-neighbours board xx yy)
                                         :x xx
                                         :y yy)
                              moves))
        (map nil
             (lambda (next)
               (brute-visit knight
                            (next-x next)
                            (next-y next)
                            callback)
               (cerror "CONTINUE" "Backtrack detected"))
             (sort moves
                   (lambda (u v)
                     (declare (fixnum u v))
                     (<= u v))
                   :key #'next-count)
             )))
  (unvisit knight x y)
  (values))
```

The results are *immediate* when trying previous tests.
For example, with a **64x64** board:

```
knight> (time
         (block nil
           (knights-tour
            0 0
            (lambda (k) (return))
            64 64)))

Evaluation took:
  0.012 seconds of real time
  0.012001 seconds of total run time (0.012001 user, 0.000000 system)
  100.00% CPU
  29,990,030 processor cycles
  6,636,048 bytes consed
```

Finding the 1728 solutions for a 5x5 board takes 42 seconds.

Here I keep the backtrack mechanism, and in order to see if we need it, I added a `cerror` expression in the search, so that we are notified as soon as the search tries another path. The following test triggers the error:

```
(time
 (dotimes (x 8)
   (dotimes (y 8)
     (block nil
       (knights-tour
        x y
        (lambda (k) (return))
        8 8)))))
```

The values for *x* and *y* for which the error is reported are respectively *2* and *1*.

---

**1** For reference, see [Daft Punk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harder,_Better,_Faster,_Stronger).

Comment: This seems like a much better way to solve it. Is there a reason for why you chose to check the move options in that particular order? If I change my version to use that, it computes 8x8 board in ~1 minute on my machine, so clearly it's more efficient for some reason.

Comment: @jkiiski There is no particular reason. I guess that the for a different starting position another order would be more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

I decided to add this as another answer instead of doing such a major edit of my other answer.

It turns out there is a [heuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour#Warnsdorf.27s_rule) for solving the problem. You simply always move to the square with the least possible moves onward.

I switched to using sort of an ad hoc graph for representing the board. The squares contain edges to squares that a knight can travel to. This way the board can be built beforehand, and the actual search doesn't need to care about the details of where the knight can move (just follow the edges). There is no need to keep a separate list of the path taken, since the edges keep the necessary information to backtrack.

It's rather lengthy due to implementing the graph, but the relevant parts are `find-tour` and `backtrack`.

Using `(knights-tour:knights-tour 0 0 8 8)` will return a two-dimensional array of `square`s, which probably isn't very useful by itself. You should pass it through `knights-tour:print-board` or `knights-tour:path-as-list`.

```
(let ((tour (knights-tour:knights-tour 0 0 8 8)))
  (knights-tour:print-board tour)
  (knights-tour:path-as-list tour))
;;   1  54  15  32  61  28  13  30 
;;  16  33  64  55  14  31  60  27 
;;  53   2  49  44  57  62  29  12 
;;  34  17  56  63  50  47  26  59 
;;   3  52  45  48  43  58  11  40 
;;  18  35  20  51  46  41   8  25 
;;  21   4  37  42  23   6  39  10 
;;  36  19  22   5  38   9  24   7 
;; => ((0 . 0) (1 . 2) (0 . 4) (1 . 6) (3 . 7) (5 . 6) (7 . 7) (6 . 5) (5 . 7)
;;     (7 . 6) (6 . 4) (7 . 2) (6 . 0) (4 . 1) (2 . 0) (0 . 1) (1 . 3) (0 . 5)
;;     (1 . 7) (2 . 5) (0 . 6) (2 . 7) (4 . 6) (6 . 7) (7 . 5) (6 . 3) (7 . 1)
;;     (5 . 0) (6 . 2) (7 . 0) (5 . 1) (3 . 0) (1 . 1) (0 . 3) (1 . 5) (0 . 7)
;;     (2 . 6) (4 . 7) (6 . 6) (7 . 4) (5 . 5) (3 . 6) (4 . 4) (3 . 2) (2 . 4)
;;     (4 . 5) (5 . 3) (3 . 4) (2 . 2) (4 . 3) (3 . 5) (1 . 4) (0 . 2) (1 . 0)
;;     (3 . 1) (2 . 3) (4 . 2) (5 . 4) (7 . 3) (6 . 1) (4 . 0) (5 . 2) (3 . 3)
;;     (2 . 1))
```

If it can't find a solution (for example (1, 0) on 5x5 board), `knights-tour` returns nil.

The squares are zero indexed.

```
(declaim (optimize (speed 3) (space 0) (safety 0) (debug 0)))

(defpackage :knights-tour
  (:use :cl)
  (:export :knights-tour
           :print-board
           :path-as-list))
(in-package :knights-tour)

;;; Function types

(declaim (ftype (function (fixnum fixnum fixnum fixnum) (or board null))
                knights-tour))
(declaim (ftype (function (square fixnum)) find-tour))
(declaim (ftype (function (square) square) backtrack))
(declaim (ftype (function (square) fixnum) count-valid-moves))
(declaim (ftype (function (square) list) neighbours))
(declaim (ftype (function (edge square) (or square null)) other-end))
(declaim (ftype (function (edge square)) set-travelled))
(declaim (ftype (function (edge square) (or (member :from :to) null)) travelled))
(declaim (ftype (function (fixnum fixnum) board) make-board))
(declaim (ftype (function ((or board null))) print-board))
(declaim (ftype (function ((or board null)) list) path-as-list))

;;; Types, Structures and Conditions

(deftype board () '(array square (* *)))

(defstruct square
  "Represents a square on a chessboard.

VISITED contains the number of moves left when this `square' was
visited, or 0 if it has not been visited.

EDGES contains a list of edges to `square's that a knight can move to
from this `square'.
"
  (visited 0 :type fixnum)
  (edges (list) :type list)
  (tries 0 :type fixnum)
  (x 0 :type fixnum)
  (y 0 :type fixnum))

(defstruct edge
  "Connects two `square's that a knight can move between.

An `edge' has two ends, TO and FROM. Both contain a `square'.

TRAVELLED contains either :FROM or :TO to signal that this edge has
been travelled from the `square' in FROM or TO slots respectively to
the other one. Contains NIL if this edge has not been travelled.

TRAVELLED should be set and read with SET-TRAVELLED and TRAVELLED.
"
  (to nil :type square)
  (from nil :type square)
  (travelled nil :type (or keyword null))
  (backtracked nil :type boolean))

(define-condition no-solution (error) ()
  (:documentation "Error raised when there is no solution."))
(define-condition too-many-tries (error) ()
  (:documentation "Error raised after too many attempts to backtrack."))

;;; Main program

(defun knights-tour (x y width height)
  "Finds a knights tour starting from point X, Y on board size WIDTH x HEIGHT.

X and Y are zero indexed. 

When a path is found, returns a two-dimensional array of
`square's. When no path is found, returns NIL.
"
  (let ((board (make-board width height)))
    (handler-case (find-tour (aref board y x) (* width height))
      (no-solution () (return-from knights-tour nil))
      (too-many-tries () (return-from knights-tour nil)))
    board))

(defun find-tour (current-square moves-left)
  "Find a knights tour starting from CURRENT-SQUARE, taking MOVES-LEFT moves.

Returns nothing. The `square's are mutated to show how many moves were
left when the knight passed through it.
"
  (when (or (not (square-p current-square))
            (minusp moves-left))
    (return-from find-tour))

  (setf (square-visited current-square) moves-left)

  ;; If the same square has been tried 1000 times, assume we're in an
  ;; infinite backtracking loop.
  (when (> (incf (square-tries current-square)) 1000)
    (error 'too-many-tries))

  (let ((next-moves (1- moves-left)))
    (unless (zerop next-moves)
      (find-tour
       (loop
          with least-moves = 9
          with least-square = nil
          with least-edge = nil

          for (edge . neighbour) in (neighbours current-square)
          for valid-moves = (if (not (travelled-from edge current-square))
                                (count-valid-moves neighbour)
                                9)

          when (< valid-moves least-moves) do
            (setf least-moves valid-moves
                  least-square neighbour
                  least-edge edge)

          finally (if least-square
                      (progn (set-travelled least-edge current-square)
                             (return least-square))
                      (progn (incf next-moves)
                             (return (backtrack current-square)))))
       next-moves))))

(defun backtrack (square)
  "Return the `square' from where the knight travelled to SQUARE.

Also unmarks SQUARE and all `edge's travelled from SQUARE.
"
  (setf (square-visited square) 0)
  (loop
     with to-edge = nil
     for edge in (square-edges square)
     ;; Unmark edges travelled from this square.
     when (travelled-from edge square) do
       (setf (edge-travelled edge) nil
             (edge-backtracked edge) nil)
     ;; Find the edge used to travel to this square...
     when (and (travelled-to edge square)
               (not (edge-backtracked edge))) do
       (setf to-edge edge)
     ;; and finally return the other end of that edge.
     finally (if to-edge
                 (progn (setf (edge-backtracked to-edge) t)
                        (return (other-end to-edge square)))
                 (error 'no-solution))))

;;; Helpers

(defun count-valid-moves (square)
  "Count valid moves from SQUARE."
  (length (neighbours square)))

(defun neighbours (square)
  "Return a list of neighbours of SQUARE."
  (loop
     for edge in (square-edges square)
     for other = (other-end edge square)
     when (zerop (square-visited other)) collect (cons edge other)))

(defun other-end (edge square)
  "Return the other end of EDGE when looking from SQUARE."
  (if (eq (edge-to edge)
          square)
      (edge-from edge)
      (edge-to edge)))

(defun set-travelled (edge square)
  "Set EDGE as travelled from SQUARE."
  (setf (edge-travelled edge)
        (if (eq (edge-to edge)
                square)
            :to :from)))

(defun travelled (edge square)
  "Has the EDGE been travelled, and from which end."
  (when (edge-travelled edge)
    (if (eq (edge-to edge)
            square)
        (if (eql (edge-travelled edge) :to)
            :from :to)
        (if (eql (edge-travelled edge) :from)
            :to :from))))

(defun travelled-from (edge square)
  "Has EDGE been travelled from SQUARE."
  (eql :from (travelled edge square)))

(defun travelled-to (edge square)
  "Has EDGE been travelled to SQUARE."
  (eql :to (travelled edge square)))

(defun make-board (width height)
  "Make a board with given WIDTH and HEIGHT."
  (let ((board (make-array (list height width)
                           :element-type 'square)))
    (dotimes (i height)
      (dotimes (j width)
        (let ((this-square (make-square :x j :y i)))
          (setf (aref board i j)
                this-square)
          (loop
             for (x-mod . y-mod) in '((-2 . -1) (2 . -1) (-1 . -2) (1 . -2))
             for target-x = (+ j x-mod)
             for target-y = (+ i y-mod)
             when (array-in-bounds-p board target-y target-x) do
               (let* ((target-square (aref board target-y target-x))
                      (edge (make-edge :to target-square
                                       :from this-square)))
                 (push edge (square-edges this-square))
                 (push edge (square-edges target-square)))))))
    board))

(defun print-board (board)
  "Print a text representation of BOARD."
  (when board
    (loop
       with (height width) = (array-dimensions board)
       with moves = (1+ (* height width))
       with col-width = (ceiling (log moves 10))
       for y from 0 below height
       do (loop
             for x from 0 below width
             do (format t " ~vd " col-width
                        (- moves (square-visited (aref board y x)))))
       do (format t "~%"))))

(defun path-as-list (board)
  "Return a list of coordinates representing the path taken."
  (when board
    (mapcar #'cdr
            (sort (loop
                     with (height width) = (array-dimensions board)
                     with result = (list)
                     for y from 0 below height
                     do (loop
                           for x from 0 below width
                           do (push (cons (square-visited (aref board y x))
                                          (cons x y))
                                    result))
                     finally (return result))
                  #'>
                  :key #'car))))

;;; Printers

(defmethod print-object ((square square) stream)
  (declare (type stream stream))
  (format stream "<(~d, ~d) ~d>"
          (square-x square)
          (square-y square)
          (square-visited square)))

(defmethod print-object ((edge edge) stream)
  (declare (type stream stream))
  (format stream "<edge :from ~a :to ~a :travelled ~a>"
          (edge-from edge)
          (edge-to edge)
          (edge-travelled edge)))
```

Comment: @coredump- Alright. I added backtracking back, although for my code it seems like it's (1, 4), (2, 7) and (4, 4) that require backtracking on 8x8. I also added a function to print the board.